# Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: ... syntax to use near 'NUMBER NOT NULL, `myEnumType` ENUM('foo', 'bar', 'alpha'), `dir' at line 1

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Started getting this error since last migration:

```
 Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NUMBER NOT NULL, `myEnumType` ENUM('foo', 'bar', 'alpha'), `dir' at line 1
```

I thought maybe MySQL Sequelize does not support enum's or a specific enum type, but it does support string enums as far as I know.

*MySql version: 5.7.30*

Any ideas? Did anyone encounter this before? Thanks

Comment: `NUMBER` is not a valid numeric data type in `mysql`, though it is a convenience class in sequelize. Do you know what table in your DB this error relates to? You might need to modify or regenerate your migration model if there are inconsistencies between it and your DB.